# mostrar todas opções de <select> sem barra de rolagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Tenho um select que trás informações de um JS, porém este select está formando barra de rolagem sendo que as opções não são muitas e há espaço para que sejam mostradas mais opções porém independente do que tente não estou conseguindo fazer com que todos os dados sejam mostrados ao invés da barra de rolagem.

Minha chamada do select no HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <span>Selecione sua localidade: </span>
        <select id="cities" class="empty" name="cities" onclick="selected(this.value)">
           <option selected >Selecionar</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui faço a organizaçao do Select

```
 var $select = $('#cities');
            $.each(items, function(index, val) {

              var optgroup = $('<optgroup>');
              optgroup.attr('label', index);

            $.each(val, function(index, val) {
              optgroup.append($('<option>', {
              text: val.loja,
              value: val.idx
                }));
              });

            $select.append(optgroup);
    });
```

Desta forma ele lê o arquivo JS e agrupa no select.

Comment: Possivelmente esse é um problema no CSS e não no JS

Comment: Renato, tentei diversas alterações no CSS e nenhuma refletiram na tela. Inacreditavelmente no IE abre sem o scroll e com todas as opções disponíveis, apenas no Chrome e no Firefox está ocorrendo isso.

Comment: seu código parece incompleto, a variável `items` não está definida, tente adicionar um código executável com `Ctrl + M` no editor

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade size para colocar a quantidade de options que o select terá, apenas com isto todas as opções serão mostradas,
 agora se você quiser remover a aparência de scroll poderá adicionar em uma div pai, o overflow:hidden.

Testado nos navegadores IE 9,Chrome 49 e Firefox 45

**Exemplo:**

```js
var select = document.getElementById("select");
select.size = select.length;
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid grey 1px;
}
#container select {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: -5px -20px -5px -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <select id="select">
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizaria isso se você tem certeza que não terá muitas opções.

Ao modificar o evento `onmousedown` para `this.size=this.options.length` você faz com que abrir o dropdown ele sempre tenha o tamanho exato do seu número de opções.

Ao adicionar o `onclick` e `onblur` como `this.size=0` você faz com que ao selecionar uma opção ou ao elemento perder o foco, ele feche todas as opções.

```
<select id="cities" class="empty" name="cities" onclick="this.size=0;" onblur="this.size=0;" onmousedown="this.size=this.options.length;">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aplicar estilos CSS ao `<select>` é uma tarefa bastante complicada, porque cada navegador renderiza de uma maneira diferente, e acredito que não tem uma maneira de controlar o tamanho do *dropdown* nativo.

Se você realmente precisa controlar a aparência do select sugiro utilizar algum plugin, como o [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) por exemplo.